# С помощью функции надо найти все простые числа от 1 до 100. Те создать еще одну функцию, которая будет передавать значения. В чем ошибка,

Tags: javascript

```
function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  } return true;
}
   
   
 function digits(){
 for (let i = 1 ; i <= 100; i++) {
   if(isPrime(true)) {
   return i;
  }
} 
}console.log(digits());
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции `isPrime(num)` аргумент `num` используется как число, а Вы в эту функцию передаёте в качестве аргумента значение `true`(Boolean). А вообще такие вопросы не стоит задавать, лучше самому отлаживать код. Подробнее: [Отладка кода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/what-is-debugging?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.)

Кстати, думаю лучше всего для этого использовать рекурсивную функцию.  Подробнее: [Рекурсия в js](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion)